# Aframe 0.9.0 Set Attribute

Tags: aframe

In previous versions I set a component on an entity with

```
entity.setAttribute('component',true)
```

Now this.data on the component is 'true' rather than the original schema.

```
i.e. 
AFRAME.registerComponent('component',{
  schema : {
    speed : {default:2},
    visible: {default:true},
  },

init: function(){
   console.log(this.data)  <==== true 
}
```

Is there a new way of setting a component on an entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`el.setAttribute('component', '')`

Answer (score 0):

el.setAttribute('component', null)

stopped the data getting overwritten